# Multiple Date Ranges for an Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data like this

```
id   date           ischanged
1    01-01-2014     0
1    02-01-2014     1
1    03-01-2014     1
1    04-01-2014     1
1    05-01-2014     0
1    06-01-2014     1
1    07-01-2014     0

2    01-01-2014     1
2    02-01-2014     1
2    03-01-2014     1
2    04-01-2014     0
2    05-01-2014     0
2    06-01-2014     1
2    07-01-2014     1
```

Is it possible to query the data to get the below results from above table based on `Ischanged` value

```
id   startdate     enddate
1    02-01-2014     04-01-2014
1    06-01-2014     06-01-2014
2    01-01-2014     03-01-2014
2    06-01-2014     07-01-2014
```

I tried my query  to join the table to self and find the first ischanged value but that will only give me results something like this

```
id   startdate     enddate
1    02-01-2014     04-01-2014
2    01-01-2014     03-01-2014
```

Is there a way to get multiple date ranges for the same ID?

Comment: Please post the query you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a bit easier with the `lag()` function, but you can still do this in SQL Server 2008.

```
select id, min(date) as startdate, max(date) as enddate
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by id order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by id, ischanged order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t 
     ) t
where ischanged = 1
group by id, grp;
```

Notice that this is using the difference of two `row_number()`s.  The first is a sequential number for all rows for an id (by date).  The second is a separate sequential number for an id and `ischanged` value.  When the `ischanged` values are consecutive, the difference is a constant -- that identifies each group.

The outer query just aggregates by this group.